# Download Large Files From Azure on Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services, android-download-manager

I'm developing an android app that uses azure mobile services. And I want to download large files from azure storage on android. I want to download large files in block or something like that. How can I do it ? Are there java library for that ?

Comment: Does Azure SDK for Java (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java) work on Android?

Comment: I don't know. If it works, Can I use it for that? I'm using azure mobile services.

Comment: No it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 3):

Blob storage service supports downloading data in chunks so it is possible to download a very large file in pieces and when all pieces have been downloaded you can assemble them to create a file.

I haven't worked with Android/Java as such so I don't know the exact details of the implementation but generally speaking this is what you would do:

- Get a Shared Access Signature (SAS) on the file (blob) you're trying to download. You can possibly use Windows Azure Mobile Service for that purpose. Make sure you get the SAS with `Read` permission on the blob. Using SAS is recommended because then you don't have to share your account credentials on the device. You can look at the tutorial here to create a SAS URL for your blob using Mobile Service (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/).
- Once you have the SAS URI, you could either use REST API directly to download the blob in chunks. You would need to invoke [`Get Blob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx) operation. The chunk size should be passed in `Range` request header. I'm not sure if Java Storage Client Library for Azure can be used on Android but if it can be used, then you don't have to use the REST API as the client library is a wrapper over the REST API.
- Once all chunks are downloaded, you can just assemble them to create a file.

Answer (score 1):

I keep hitting this outdated question from Google, so for the sake of completeness , I have added this up to date answer (I tried to add this as a comment, but it was too long).

The link for mobile services is :

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/develop/mobile/android-samples/

and the link for the Microsoft Azure Storage SDK is :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android

Answer (score 0):

The current Java library for Azure Storage does not support Android at the moment (this is a feature request we have, and is something we are currently investigating).  At a high level it is not recommended to use full shared key auth on a mobile device due to security reasons, as such using SAS or Anonymous access is the preferred scenario. If your scenario is to simply download a blob a simple GET request with the range header will be sufficient, but you will need to implement the logic to aggregate the blob ranges in your application.